# Is there a way to refactor the julia code below in order to avoid the loop/malloc?

Tags: performance, malloc, profiling, julia

```
m,n =size(l.x)
for batch=1:m
  l.ly = l.y[batch,:]
  l.jacobian .= -l.ly .* l.ly'
  l.jacobian[diagind(l.jacobian)] .= l.ly.*(1.0.-l.ly)
  # # n x 1 = n x n * n x 1
  l.dldx[batch,:] = l.jacobian * DLDY[batch,:]
end
return l.dldx
```

`l.x` is a `m` by `n` matrix. `l.y` is another matrix with the same size as `l.x`. My goal is to create another `m` by `n` matrix, `l.dldx`, in which each row is the result of the operation inside the for loop. Can any one spot further optimization for this block of code? The code above is part of https://github.com/stevenygd/NN.jl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should implement the same calculation and is more efficient:

```
l.dldx = l.y .* (DLDY .- sum( l.y .* DLDY , 2))
```

There might be a slight improvement available by refactoring the `sum` into a loop.

As the question does not have runnable code, or a test case, it is hard to give definite benchmarks, so feedback would be welcome.

UPDATE

Here is the code above with explicit loops:

```
function calc_dldx(y,DLDY)
    tmp = zeros(eltype(y),size(y,1))
    dldx = similar(y)
    @inbounds for j=1:size(y,2)
        for i=1:size(y,1)
            tmp[i] += y[i,j]*DLDY[i,j]
        end
    end
    @inbounds for j=1:size(y,2)
        for i=1:size(y,1)
            dldx[i,j] = y[i,j]*(DLDY[i,j]-tmp[i])
        end
    end
    return dldx
end
```

The long version should run even faster. A good way to measure the performance of code is using the BenchmarkTools package.

Comment: Packing the calculation into a couple of `for` loops brings it down to 2 allocations and gives *another 5x speed improvement*. It is trivial, but I will add the code if requested.

Comment: Please add the codes as well! You are a god in Julia performance.

Comment: Can you also explain how to you refactor the entire block of codes to just one line? I don't understand where in your code did you calculate the diagonal entries of the jacobian matrix.

Comment: The code provided by the answer runs comparably the same speed as my original code; for l.x and DLDY with size 10 * 1000, and taking the average by running it 50 times, my old code uses 0.000433838 seconds while the refactored one uses 0.000430965.

Comment: @HaonanChen The code for the longer version (but faster) is added to the answer. How fast does it work now?

Comment: The trick in the refactor is splitting the diagonal correction from the rest of the jacobian entries. The diagonal correction is implemented with `DLDY` outside the `sum` and the jacobian calculation is the same as the `-sum(...)` part.